How to limit file size in multipart uploads to R2 bucket using Node.js?
I'm working on a Node.js application that allows users to upload files to an R2 bucket using multipart uploads. I want to restrict the maximum file size that users can upload to 200MB.
if(req.body.fileSize > 20971520){
    throw new Error('Max 200MB allowed');
    return;
}
const params = {
    Bucket,
    Key,
    ContentLength: req.body.fileSize,
    ContentType: req.body.contentType,
    Metadata: {
        'x-amz-meta-file-hash': req.body.fileHash,
    },
};
const command = new CreateMultipartUploadCommand({ ...params });

I create the file hash on the client and send the file hash, content type, and file size from the frontend to the backend. I pass these values as parameters. Will the file hash and file size prevent users from uploading files larger than 200MB?
If not, what is the best way to prevent this?
